# WARN: Protobuf file not found, when using SonarQube

Tags: tfs, msbuild, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I'm just getting started with SonarQube and it does run so far.
The IT department has set up SonarQube 6.2 for our Team Foundation Server and I have installed and configured the msbuild scanner on my BuildAgent.

I call the msbuild scanner in the XAML-Template of my build definition and it does run, but it gives me a warning, which makes my build "partially succeeded".
This is the error message:

> 07:53:01.658 WARN: Protobuf file not found:
>   d:\b\210\474.sonarqube\out\ReferenceManager_x86_Release_6561\output-cs\issues.pb

The issues.pb file is really missing, but why do I get an error/warning for this? I do not get this, when I run the scanner and msbuild from command line, only when in runs in team build. But when running on command line there also is no issues.pb file.

When running the scanner from the command line, I get this output:

```
09:34:05.959 INFO: 97 files indexed
09:34:05.985 INFO: Quality profile for cs: Sonar way
09:34:05.992 DEBUG: Code colorizer, supported languages: 
09:34:07.008 DEBUG: 'Generic Coverage Report' skipped because one of the required properties is missing
09:34:07.009 DEBUG: 'Generic Test Executions Report' skipped because one of the required properties is missing
09:34:07.018 DEBUG: 'SurefireSensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
09:34:07.023 DEBUG: 'JaCoCoSensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
09:34:07.025 DEBUG: 'JavaSquidSensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
09:34:07.025 DEBUG: 'JavaScript Squid Sensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
09:34:07.027 DEBUG: Sensors : Lines Sensor -> SCM Sensor -> C# -> Coverage Report Import -> Coverage Report Import -> Unit Test Results Import -> XmlFileSensor -> Zero Coverage Sensor -> Code Colorizer Sensor -> CPD Block Indexer
09:34:07.029 INFO: Sensor Lines Sensor
09:34:07.279 INFO: Sensor Lines Sensor (done) | time=250ms
09:34:07.279 INFO: Sensor SCM Sensor
09:34:07.279 INFO: SCM Publisher is disabled
09:34:07.281 INFO: Sensor SCM Sensor (done) | time=2ms
09:34:07.281 INFO: Sensor C#
09:34:07.292 INFO: SonarAnalyzer.Scanner needs to be executed: false
09:34:07.292 INFO: Importing analysis results from C:\Users\Build-SW-Dev\Desktop\.sonarqube\out\ReferenceManager_x86_Release_5730\output-cs
09:34:08.749 INFO: Importing Roslyn report
09:34:08.998 INFO: Sensor C# (done) | time=1717ms
```

When running the scanner during team build, I get this output:

```
11:12:51.390 INFO: 97 files indexed
11:12:51.422 INFO: Quality profile for cs: Sonar way
11:12:51.422 DEBUG: Code colorizer, supported languages: 
11:12:52.468 DEBUG: 'Generic Coverage Report' skipped because one of the required properties is missing
11:12:52.468 DEBUG: 'Generic Test Executions Report' skipped because one of the required properties is missing
11:12:52.468 DEBUG: 'SurefireSensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
11:12:52.468 DEBUG: 'JaCoCoSensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
11:12:52.468 DEBUG: 'JavaSquidSensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
11:12:52.468 DEBUG: 'JavaScript Squid Sensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
11:12:52.484 DEBUG: Sensors : Lines Sensor -> SCM Sensor -> C# -> Coverage Report Import -> Coverage Report Import -> Unit Test Results Import -> XmlFileSensor -> Zero Coverage Sensor -> Code Colorizer Sensor -> CPD Block Indexer
11:12:52.484 INFO: Sensor Lines Sensor
11:12:52.562 INFO: Sensor Lines Sensor (done) | time=78ms
11:12:52.562 INFO: Sensor SCM Sensor
11:12:52.562 INFO: SCM Publisher is disabled
11:12:52.562 INFO: Sensor SCM Sensor (done) | time=0ms
11:12:52.562 INFO: Sensor C#
11:12:52.562 INFO: SonarAnalyzer.Scanner needs to be executed: false
11:12:52.562 INFO: Importing analysis results from d:\b\210\474\.sonarqube\out\ReferenceManager_x86_Release_1481\output-cs
11:12:53.078 WARN: Protobuf file not found: d:\b\210\474\.sonarqube\out\ReferenceManager_x86_Release_1481\output-cs\issues.pb
11:12:53.718 INFO: Sensor C# (done) | time=1156ms
```

Didn't find anything about this error using google. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? Usually, a warning won't cause your build partially succeeded, do you have particular setting?

Comment: We are using TFS 2015 and the xaml build template. I call "MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe end" in the post-build parts of the Test-section of the XAML template, as described her:
https://github.com/SonarSource-VisualStudio/sonar-.net-documentation/blob/master/doc/analyze-from-tfs.md

TFS converts this warning to an error:
    Run optional script after Test Runner
     09:41:38.799 WARN: Protobuf file not found: d:\b\210\474\.sonarqube\out\ReferenceManager_x86_Release_4068\output-cs\issues.pb

This is marked with the red error cross when you view the logs in VS...

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the code in CSharpSencor.java, I think the difference between command line build and team build is caused by the RoslynReportPath:

```
void executeInternal(SensorContext context) {
  boolean requiresAnalyzerScannerExecution = !config.isReportsComingFromMSBuild();

  LOG.info("SonarAnalyzer.Scanner needs to be executed: " + requiresAnalyzerScannerExecution);

  String roslynReportPath = settings.getString(config.getRoslynJsonReportPathProperty());
  boolean hasRoslynReportPath = roslynReportPath != null;

  Path protobufReportsDirectory;
  if (requiresAnalyzerScannerExecution) {
    // MSBuild 12 or MSBuild 14 with old scanner
    analyze(!hasRoslynReportPath, context);
    protobufReportsDirectory = protobufReportPathForMSBuild12(context);
  } else {
    protobufReportsDirectory = config.protobufReportPathFromScanner();
  }

  LOG.info("Importing analysis results from " + protobufReportsDirectory.toAbsolutePath().toString());
  importResults(context, protobufReportsDirectory, !hasRoslynReportPath);

  if (hasRoslynReportPath) {
    LOG.info("Importing Roslyn report");
    importRoslynReport(roslynReportPath, context);
  }
}
```

command line build:

```
...
Generating SonarQube project properties file to C:\Users\Build-SW-Dev\Desktop\.sonarqube\out\sonar-project.properties
The supplied Code Analysis ErrorLog file is a valid json file and does not need to be fixed: d:\b\210\474\src\TPA\DevTools_Source\internal\ReferenceManager\main\ReferenceManager\bin\Release\ReferenceManager.exe.RoslynCA.json
...
08:41:57.276 INFO: Sensor C#
08:41:57.291 INFO: SonarAnalyzer.Scanner needs to be executed: false
08:41:57.291 INFO: Importing analysis results from C:\Users\Build-SW-Dev\Desktop\.sonarqube\out\ReferenceManager_x86_Release_6194\output-cs
08:41:59.948 INFO: Importing Roslyn report
08:42:00.448 INFO: Sensor C# (done) | time=3172ms
```

team build:

```
...
Generating SonarQube project properties file to d:\b\210\474\.sonarqube\out\sonar-project.properties
No Code Analysis ErrorLog file found at d:\b\210\474\bin\ReferenceManager.exe.RoslynCA.json.
...
11:12:52.562 INFO: Sensor C#
11:12:52.562 INFO: SonarAnalyzer.Scanner needs to be executed: false
11:12:52.562 INFO: Importing analysis results from d:\b\210\474\.sonarqube\out\ReferenceManager_x86_Release_1481\output-cs
11:12:53.078 WARN: Protobuf file not found: d:\b\210\474\.sonarqube\out\ReferenceManager_x86_Release_1481\output-cs\issues.pb
11:12:53.718 INFO: Sensor C# (done) | time=1156ms
```

While I do not have a solution to that yet, a workaround is to just redirect the output of the msbuild scanner into a file. TFS then does not see the warning and does not make the build partially succeeded.

edit:
Now I have found the root cause :) During team build, all output files get moved into a subfolder by a script. That's why SonarQube cannot find the file 'd:\b\210\474\bin\ReferenceManager.exe.RoslynCA.json'.
The file is located in a subfolder...